# HTML Select Element

Tags: css, forms, selecteditem

I am trying to style the Select element using http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

[image]
[image]

the options are starting well above the button.

Am not able to style it. could someone help me how to modify it.

Link: http://bakasura.in/king/forms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a height of 30px to the `select.styled` class, the menu will appear in the correct location.

Comment: am wondering where to add that in the code. it works in firefox.. but there is such class in the css file

Comment: I believe it's being added to the page dynamically using Javascript. (forms.js i think). You can go ahead and create a new selector of the same name in your own CSS to add the height though.